# The start date is saved to the database instead of the date selected in the DataPicker

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

Hello i have weird problem. I want save date from DataPicker to Database.

**In View**

```
<DatePicker Name="Date" 
            SelectedDate="{Binding Path=Date, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
```

**In ViewModel** -> if the user doesn't select any date from DatePicker, the default value is set - today's date

```
public DateTime Date
{
    get { return item.date == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Today : item.date; }
    set
    {
        if (value != item.date)
        {
            item.date = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Date);
        }
    }
}
```

**First case:** the user selects a date other than today in DatePicker

**Breakpoint:** Date {12.02.2020 00:00:00} System.DateTime

**Result:** everything is ok, in Database is saved 12.02.2020

---

**Second case:** the user selects a date today in DatePicker

**Breakpoint:** Date    {27.02.2020 00:00:00}   System.DateTime

**Result:** everything is ok, in Database is saved 27.02.2020

---

**Third case:** the user doesn't select date (date is set automatic)

**Breakpoint:** Date    {27.02.2020 00:00:00}   System.DateTime

**Result:** everything is wrong, in Database is saved 1.1.1

Comment: The issue may be in the code that saves the date to the database. Can you share that?

Comment: `public override void save() { ATMAEntites.SprzedawcySprzedaz.Add(item); ATMAEntites.SaveChanges(); }`

Comment: It's of type `DateTime` it has to have a value. Maybe it should be `DateTime?`

Comment: I try this, but it doesn't help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that the property value is only getting set to the correct value in the `get` method, but Entity Framework doesn't track changes that way - I believe you'd have to tell EF that the object property has been modified.

I *think* something like this should do the trick (before you call `SaveChanges`):

```
dbContext.Entry(item).Property(i => i.Date).IsModified = true;
```